# A way to embed SE posts on other sites with interactivity (upvotes, etc)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often think about reposting a Stack Exchange post on another site (forum, blog, etc), the problem is, while I'm allowed to do that by the license (with proper attribution, etc) I find it unfair to the original poster because most people won't bother following the link to the original post to upvote the question.

It would be nice to have a feature to embed an interactive version of a post that would use the current user's session cookie (if they are a member of the corresponding SE site and are logged in) to allow them to upvote/downvote the post directly and optionally see the latest version of it (when embedding, the user should be able to select whether he wants to display only that particular revision or the latest one).

Comment: "Stack Exchange Social Plugin". Sounds weird... but useful. :)

Comment: For that to work it would pretty much require cross domain AJAX requests, and most browsers don't let you do that.

Comment: @Servy it can be done with standard client side API, same way Facebook, Twitter, and many others already have.